# What are the pros|cons of using AJAX calls to retrieve an HTML page vs. using window.location or a hyperlink to go to the page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, express, button, response

I am looking to understand the differences in methods when switching pages in the browser. My understanding is as follows:

- anchor tags `<a href = "#">...</a>` can be used to redirect pages using text & pics (non-buttons)
- button elements `<button id = "go" onClick = "fx()">` have attributes that can trigger next actions

Both of the following buttons should write to your console logs:
Click One

```js
function fx(){
     console.log("Thanks for taking the time to review my post!");
}
```

```html
<button onClick="fx()">Click One</button>
```

Click Two

```js
$("#go").on("click", function(e){
//this callback keeps the screen steady then calls an AJAX function
     e.preventDefault();

     fakeAJAX("/gone", function(resp){
     //$.get("/gone", function(resp){
     //this callback delivers the response from the AJAX.get method
          console.log(resp);

     });
});

function fakeAJAX(words, funct){
//this function is meant to simulate modules.export = fx(app){
//it should respond with the result of anything matching AJAX call

     if(words == "/gone"){
     //this would be app.get("/gone", function(req, res){
          
          console.log("Your input helps me become a better #dev!");
          //this would be res.send("...");
          
       }//closing out app.get

}//} closing out modules.export simulation
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="go">Click Two</button>
```

In a recent exercise, I've had difficulty switching pages using a button...I want to be able to use the res.send(?) format (demonstrated in the `Click Two` example) to return the page that I want, but so far it has not worked; the best result that I have is the entire html from the destination page printed as plain text in the browser console...(I'll add a link to that problem)

The advice from other devs is to change pages using hyperlinks and window.location; I can admit that I have had success changing pages using the latter of those two recommendations, but I want to know why my preferred method is circumvented. If any of you could answer any of these, you would help me understand how to use these page-changing methods

- what is the "cost" of using the AJAX call to return destination pages?
- how is the AJAX method viewed in the working #dev community vs hyperlinks and window.location?
- what are the scenarios where each of these methods make more sense than the others and when are they doing too much or not doing enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to have the browser window go to a new URL and there's no special pre-processing in the web page involved, then just allow the user to click a hyperlink and let the browser handle it all.  This will work everywhere, even if Javascript is disabled.  And, there's really no reason for Javascript to be involved - that's just extra steps that are unnecessary and creates more things to code, test and operate.

If, on the other hand, there is processing involved client-side before going to a new page such as you're computing the URL based on input or you're checking to see if everything has been done that needs to be done before going to the next step (client-side validation), then you can use Javascript to do that validation and then set `window.location` to the new URL when the validation is complete.

Ajax is most appropriate to fetch new content when you want things like this:

1. You want to stay on the same page URL (in the URL bar in the browser).
2. When you want to insert new content into the existing page, keeping at least some of the current content in place and staying on the same URL in the browser.
3. When you're doing some server-side transaction (such as deleting an item from a list) and wish to stay on the same page after the transaction is complete.  In this case, you might issue the Ajax call to delete the item and then when the Ajax call returns successfully, you remove the item from the list in the current page and leave the user to then choose another operation in the same page.
4. When you wish to retrieve some data (not HTML), usually in JSON format, and use that data to then modify the current page.

If all you're doing is just going to a new page, then just let the user click a link and let the browser take your user to the new page.  There really is no reason for Javascript to be involved in such a simple operation.

And, none of these features we're talking about affect the server one-way or the other.  If the new URL is `/clicked`, then you can create a route for that URL and use `res.send()`, `res.render()` or `res.sendFile()` or something like that to send the response for that route handler in Express and that will work just fine no matter how that URL is requested (via a clicked link in the browser, via Javascript setting `window.location` or via Javascript retrieving the content manually and inserting it in a page.  The server doesn't care how the client made the request.  The request is to get the contents of a web page and the server happily carries out that request, no matter how the client is using it.

One time that the server would care what the client was doing is if the client just wants JSON data instead of a full HTML web page.  In that case, you'd design a route specifically for the JSON request and you'd generate JSON and send that back rather than sending back HTML.

Comment: could you find me on frank_misir@hotmail.com?